# Can I tie into current outlet for waste pump?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, pump, sump-pump

I added a waste pump in our basement to transfer sewage and am needing to add an outlet. I'm wanting to know if I can tie into an the existing outlet for the sump pump? Or does it need to be on it's own breaker?

the idea here is we don't won't both pumps to trigger at the same time.

[image]

Edit: Additional information:

- Location is NE Kansas.
- The new waste pump is a 3/4 HP, 10 amp. It
  requires 120 volts.
- The outlet pictured has a submersible non-waste
  pump and also has a humidifier plugged in.
- The existing outlet is the only thing on that breaker.
- I am unsure of what amperage/volts are required for the sump pump.

Comment: Where in the world are you located? What amperage breaker is protecting that circuit? Is there anything else on that circuit? What are the amp requirements of the sump and of the waste pump? Please [edit] this info into your question.

Comment: I presume the sump is the heavy gauge black cord. What's the power brick with thin white cord powering?

Comment: white cord is powering a whole-house humidifier.

Comment: what is the amperage on the breaker?  Are you using the float to activate the sewage pump or doing it manually?

Comment: What amperage is the breaker, and how many HP is the existing sump pump motor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than cost, there should be no negative to putting in a new circuit for your waste pump.  It looks like that existing outlet is already set up as a dedicated circuit (only one outlet, rather than a typical duplex outlet), so rewiring would be necessary anyway to provide a real outlet for the waste pump (and don't use that power tap).  Your new waste pump rated at 10A, and likely a sump pump rated at not much less, so if both are running, they could draw up to ~20A, which if you're lucky, is what the circuit is rated for, but we can't tell that without more information.

But, it would be very short-sighted to have them on one circuit where a tripped breaker would take them both out.  Much safer to have them on separate breakers, so if one goes, the other is still functional.

Comment: Good point about having a dedicated circuit for redundancy, if not for load considerations.